# R select all rows from a dataframe where the value of a column intersects a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one of my columns is a vector. I would like to select all the rows from my dataframe where that column intersects another vector.

EDIT:
Here is example code and output.

```
require(dplyr)

# DataSet
df = read.csv('data/exampledata.csv', na.strings=c(""), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[is.na(df)] <- 'None'
df$COLUMN3 <- strsplit(df$COLUMN3, "/")
dput(df)
myVector <- c("me", "stackoverflow")
df[length(intersect(df$COLUMN3, myVector)) > 0,] # doesn't work
```

Output:

```
structure(list(COLUMN1 = c("something", "something", "something"), COLUMN2 = c("something", "something", "something"), COLUMN3 = list(c("please", "help", "me"), c("please", "stackoverflow"), c("im", "desperate"))), .Names = c("COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
column3 = list(c("please", "help", "me"), c("please", "stackoverflow"), c("im", "desperate"))
myVector <- c("me", "please")
idx <- which(sapply(column3, function(x) length(intersect(myVector, x))) > 0)
```

idx should give `c(1,2)` as you desired. Then do `df[idx,]`

Btw, it is not a good idea to use list of a vector as one of data frame column. It kinda works... and doesn't work, depending on operations. `data.table` supports it better.

Comment: Great! That works perfectly. I upvoted your answer but since I have less than 15 reputation it says that it won't show up :/

I'll look into data.table. Thanks for the suggestion!